# No onMessage events on Runtime (Java JMS MessageListener on Oracle Queue)

Tags: java, oracle, queue, jms, listener

### Purpose

I created `MyListener.java` to monitor my Oracle Queue MY_QUEUE and `MyConsumer.java` implement my own `MessageListener.onMessage` functionality.
As soon as I enqueue some entries into MY_QUEUE I want the MessageListener to output "New Message..." onto the console.

### Problem

The Queue entries will only be processed on the initial application start. If additional entries get enqueued while the application is already runnning the MessageListener.onMessage function won't get triggered.

#### Example

1. Run Application with 5 entries already in queue. Output:

   > Initialized...
   >   Sleeping...
   >   New Message...
   >   New Message...
   >   New Message...
   >   New Message...
   >   New Message...
   >   Sleeping...
   >   Sleeping...
2. Quit Application and run the Application. Enqueue entries on runtime. Output:

   > Initialized...
   >   Sleeping...
   >   Sleeping...
   >   Sleeping...
   >   Sleeping...  (Queue entries got inserted about at this time)
   >   Sleeping...
   >   Sleeping...
   >   Sleeping...
   >   Sleeping...
3. Quit Application and run the Application again (Entries from 2. are still in queue). Output:

   > Initialized...
   >   Sleeping...
   >   New Message...
   >   New Message...
   >   New Message...
   >   New Message...
   >   New Message...
   >   Sleeping...
   >   Sleeping...

#### MyListener

```
package example;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.QueueConnection;
import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.QueueSession;
import javax.jms.Session;

import oracle.jms.AQjmsFactory;
import oracle.jms.AQjmsSession;

public class MyListener {

    private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "MY_QUEUE";
    private static final String QUEUE_USER = "myuser";
    private static final String QUEUE_PW = "mypassword";
    private QueueConnection queueConnection;
    private QueueSession queueSession;

    public MyListener() throws JMSException {
        QueueConnectionFactory QFac = AQjmsFactory.getQueueConnectionFactory("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "orcl", 1521, "thin");
        this.queueConnection = QFac.createQueueConnection(QUEUE_USER, QUEUE_PW);
        this.queueSession = this.queueConnection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            MyListener myListener = new MyListener();
            Queue queue = ((AQjmsSession) myListener.queueSession).getQueue(QUEUE_USER, QUEUE_NAME);

            MessageConsumer mq = ((AQjmsSession) myListener.queueSession).createReceiver(queue);
            MyConsumer mc = new MyConsumer();
            mq.setMessageListener(mc);

            myListener.queueConnection.start();

            System.out.println("Initialized...");

            while (true) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Sleeping...");
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Application closed");
        }

    }

}
```

#### MyConsumer

```
package example;

import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;

public class MyConsumer implements MessageListener{

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message arg0) {
        System.out.println("New Message...");

    }

}
```

#### PL/SQL script to enqueue entries

```
DECLARE
   msg                  SYS.aq$_jms_text_message;
   enqueue_options      DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
   message_properties   DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T;
   message_handle       RAW (16);
   i                    NUMBER;
BEGIN
   msg := sys.aq$_jms_text_message.construct;
   msg.set_text ('Testmessage');
   enqueue_options.visibility := DBMS_AQ.immediate;
   message_properties.priority := 1;
   i := 0;

   WHILE i < 5
   LOOP
      DBMS_AQ.enqueue (queue_name           => 'MY_QUEUE',
                       enqueue_options      => enqueue_options,
                       message_properties   => message_properties,
                       payload              => msg,
                       msgid                => message_handle);
      i := i + 1;
   END LOOP;

   COMMIT;
END;
```

#### Additional Information

Database: Oracle 11g2
Java Runtime: 1.6
Maven Dependencies:

- oracle-jdbc (11.2.0.4.0)
- xdb (1.0)
- aqapi (1.3)
- jmscommon (1.3.1_02)

Can someone tell me why the onMessage function won't get triggered once I enqueue new entries on runtime?

EDIT: OK, I stopped using JMS and now use the old AQ dequeue approach to get my messages asynchronously. I might come back and try to figure out as to why it's not working with the code above but that's low priority right now.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially as soon as you create the `AQjmsQueueReceiver` and set its message listener the `receive()` method will exit and the `AQjmsQueueReceiver` will fall out of scope.  I assume it's being invoked from the `main` method which also means the program will exit.  You need to:

1. Modify your application so that your JMS objects don't fall out of scope (because they will get garbage-collected).
2. Prevent your program from exiting while its waiting for messages.

Comment: 1. & 2. I did that by coding a Thread.sleep(1000) in a while(true) loop right after the queueConnection.start(); but nothing is happening afterwards. Do the object still fall out of scope if I do this? Can you please show me an example on how it should look like? I just can‘t find the correct solution with the documentation

Comment: If you loop in same scope as the variables then they shouldn't fall out of scope. It's worth noting that neither of your questions on this topic have what I would consider "correct" code. Based on what you're saying, you've written correct code but it still doesn't work. I would say that either you haven't actually written correct code or there is a bug in the underlying JMS client/server implementation. At the very least, please update your question with the most recent, most correct code you have.

Comment: I edited this question to represent the current (and in my thoughts correct) code.