# Correct approach to initialize an asynchronous JMS Listener and let it run infinitely

Tags: oracle, asynchronous, queue, jms, listener

I use the following application to connect to my oracle database, register a queue listener and wait for enqueued messages:

```
package sample;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.QueueConnection;
import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.QueueSession;
import javax.jms.Session;

import oracle.jms.AQjmsFactory;
import oracle.jms.AQjmsSession;

public class MyThread extends Thread {

    private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "MY_QUEUE";
    private static final String QUEUE_USER = "myuser";
    private static final String QUEUE_PW = "mypassword";
    private boolean running;

    public MyThread() {
        this.running = true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyThread mt = new MyThread();
        mt.start();
    }

    private QueueConnection getQueueConnection() throws JMSException {
        QueueConnectionFactory QFac = AQjmsFactory.getQueueConnectionFactory("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "orcl", 1521, "thin");
        QueueConnection QCon = QFac.createQueueConnection(QUEUE_USER, QUEUE_PW);
        return QCon;
    }

    @Override
    public void interrupt() {
        this.running = false;
        super.interrupt();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            QueueConnection queueConnection = getQueueConnection();
            QueueSession queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Queue queue = ((AQjmsSession) queueSession).getQueue(QUEUE_USER, QUEUE_NAME);

            while (running) {
                System.out.println("Starting...");

                queueConnection.start();
                MessageConsumer mq = ((AQjmsSession) queueSession).createReceiver(queue);
                MyListener listener = new MyListener();
                mq.setMessageListener(listener);

                System.out.println("... Done, now sleep a bit and redo");

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Closing Application");
            queueSession.close();
            queueConnection.close();

        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Once a message got enqueued the onMessage function will append a message into a textfiles content:

```
package sample;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;

public class MyListener implements MessageListener{

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message arg0) {
        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/temp/output/messages.txt", true)));
            out.println("New Message arrived");
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

On runtime my console output looks like this:

> Starting...
>   ... Done, now sleep a bit an redo
>   Starting...
>   ... Done, now sleep a bit an redo
>   Starting...
>   ... Done, now sleep a bit an redo
>   Starting...
>   ... Done, now sleep a bit an redo

If there where any enqueues the file will contain the new messages.
So: I can dequeue Events and the onMessage event will be triggered with this code.

**Now to my question**: I'm pretty sure waiting 5 seconds to register the Listener again (and call queueConnection.start() to receive the onMessage calls) is not the correct approach. But if I don't do this there won't be any onMessage events (File stays empty).

What is the correct approach to start listening to a queue infinitely without a fixed Thread.sleep() call and without the need to register the listener again even if there weren't any events?

#### Additional Information

Database: Oracle 11g2
Java Runtime: 1.6
Maven Dependencies:

- oracle-jdbc (11.2.0.4.0)
- xdb (1.0)
- aqapi (1.3)
- jmscommon (1.3.1_02)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to run a thread to create a JMS consumer and set its message listener. The whole point of a JMS message listener is to receive message asynchronously (functionality which you appear to be trying to duplicate for some reason).

You simply need to create the JMS consumer and set the message listener and then ensure the consumer isn't closed. Depending on how the application is written it is sometimes necessary to have a `while` loop to make sure the program doesn't terminate and therefore close the consumer.  Your thread isn't doing that.  It's letting the consumer fall out of scope after waiting for messages for 5 seconds which means that it will be garbage collected and I expect for most JMS implementations that means it will be closed. It could be worse than that, though. By not explicitly closing the consumer and just letting it fall out of scope you could be leaking consumers which would eventually bog down your message broker. This is not only sloppy programming, but potentially problematic for other users trying to consume messages.

Comment: Which command closes my consumer after 5 seconds? Is it because I create a new one after 5 seconds? How do I avoid closing my consumer?  
Do you have any other hints on how I should change my application to work how I want it to work?  
Thank you for your time!

Comment: I updated my answer to clarify what happens after the 5 second `sleep()`. In my opinion your "application" needs to be completely rewritten to use the JMS API as it was designed to be used (e.g. eliminate the `Thread` implementation, only create a single consumer, etc.).

Comment: Thank you. I tried to do just that in the past and faced the problem that I did not receive any onMessage notification while the application ran. See "Main Application: Listener" in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53223746/no-onmessage-events-on-runtime-java-jms-messagelistener-on-oracle-queue).  
I also put a while loop right after the queueConnection.start(); to check if the consumer was still available and it was. I just didn't get any notification.

Comment: I just provided an answer on that question. That code suffered from a similar problem as the code from this question.

Comment: You provided the details on why my code is not working as intended in this case (Consumer gets closed + garbage collected) so I will accept your answer as the solution. 
I updated the question mentioned in my previous comment to represent the current state of my code.